# How to write stereo wav files in Python?

Tags: python, wav, wave

The following code writes a simple sine at frequency 400Hz to a mono WAV file. How should this code be changed in order to produce a **stereo** WAV file. The second channel should be in a different frequency.

```
import math
import wave
import struct

freq = 440.0
data_size = 40000
fname = "WaveTest.wav"
frate = 11025.0  # framerate as a float
amp = 64000.0     # multiplier for amplitude

sine_list_x = []
for x in range(data_size):
    sine_list_x.append(math.sin(2*math.pi*freq*(x/frate)))

wav_file = wave.open(fname, "w")

nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = int(frate)
nframes = data_size
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"

wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes,
    comptype, compname))

for s in sine_list_x:
    # write the audio frames to file
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(s*amp/2)))

wav_file.close()
```

Comment: Set `nchannels = 2` for a start ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Build a parallel `sine_list_y` list with the other frequency / channel, set `nchannels=2`, and in the output loop use `for s, t in zip(sine_list_x, sine_list_y):` as the header clause, and a body with two `writeframes` calls -- one for `s`, one for `t`.  IOW, corresponding frames for the two channels "alternate" in the file.

See e.g. [this](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html) page for a thorough description of all possible WAV file formats, and I quote:

> Multi-channel digital audio samples
>   are stored as interlaced wave data
>   which simply means that the audio
>   samples of a multi-channel (such as
>   stereo and surround) wave file are
>   stored by cycling through the audio
>   samples for each channel before
>   advancing to the next sample time.
>   This is done so that the audio files
>   can be played or streamed before the
>   entire file can be read. This is handy
>   when playing a large file from disk
>   (that may not completely fit into
>   memory) or streaming a file over the
>   Internet. The values in the diagram
>   below would be stored in a Wave file
>   in the order they are listed in the
>   Value column (top to bottom).

and the following table clearly shows the channels' samples going left, right, left, right, ...

Answer (score 3):

For an example producing a stereo `.wav` file, see the [`test_wave.py` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_wave.py?view=markup).
The test produces an all-zero file.
You can modify by inserting alternating sample values.

```
nchannels = 2
sampwidth = 2
framerate = 8000
nframes = 100

# ...

    def test_it(self):
        self.f = wave.open(TESTFN, 'wb')
        self.f.setnchannels(nchannels)
        self.f.setsampwidth(sampwidth)
        self.f.setframerate(framerate)
        self.f.setnframes(nframes)
        output = '\0' * nframes * nchannels * sampwidth
        self.f.writeframes(output)
        self.f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the SciPy and NumPy libraries. In the below example, we produce a stereo wave file where the left channel has a low-frequency tone while the right channel has a higher-frequency tone. (Note: Use VLC player to play the audio)

*To install SciPy, see:* https://pypi.org/project/scipy/

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

# User input
duration=5.0
toneFrequency_left=500 #Hz (20,000 Hz max value)
toneFrequency_right=1200 #Hz (20,000 Hz max value)

# Constants
samplingFrequency=48000

# Generate Tones
time_x=np.arange(0, duration, 1.0/float(samplingFrequency))
toneLeft_y=np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * toneFrequency_left * time_x)
toneRight_y=np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * toneFrequency_right * time_x)

# A 2D array where the left and right tones are contained in their respective rows
tone_y_stereo=np.vstack((toneLeft_y, toneRight_y))

# Reshape 2D array so that the left and right tones are contained in their respective columns
tone_y_stereo=tone_y_stereo.transpose()

# Produce an audio file that contains stereo sound
wavfile.write('stereoAudio.wav', samplingFrequency, tone_y_stereo)
```

#### Environment Notes

Version Used
Python 3.7.1

- Python 3.7.1
- SciPy 1.1.0

Comment: When I try to play the audio file your code generates, both Windows media player and Groove music player throw an unsupported codec error: 0xc00d5212. Which player did you use?

Comment: @Naktis, I only tested with VLC player and Apple Quicktime. Also, I just tested that the generated file plays as expected when using VLC player on a Windows machine. You can download VLC player for free here: https://www.videolan.org