# python handle wav file with wave and numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to extract frequency from .wav files. So I'm using python wave and numpy, I'm almost done! But I face an error.. I followed this url's answer : [Extracting frequencies from a wav file python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996620/extracting-frequencies-from-a-wav-file-python)

when I exract frequency from .wav file that created myself by following that answer, it succeed. However, when I exract frequency from .wav file that recorded by mic. it raised an error :

> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 288768 bytes

following is my code

```
import wave
import struct
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wf = wave.open('test6.wav', 'rb')
    frame = wf.getnframes()
    data_size = wf.getnframes()
    frate = wf.getframerate()
    data = wf.readframes(data_size)
    wf.close()
    duration = frame / float(frate)


    data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=data_size), data)
    data = np.array(data)

    w = np.fft.fft(data)
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(w))
    print(freqs.min(), freqs.max())
    # (-0.5, 0.499975)

    # Find the peak in the coefficients
    idx = np.argmax(np.abs(w))
    freq = freqs[idx]
    freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * frate)
    print('freqiency: ',freq_in_hertz)
    print('duration: ',duration)
```

288768 in error message is exactly double of `data_size`. 
So when I use `data_size=wf.getnframes()*2`, it does not raise error. But, it raise an error with file that created by code.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the size of the buffer is exactly double `data_size`, I would guess that the .wav file you recorded with your mic has two channels instead of one. You can verify this by looking at the output of `wf.getnchannels()`. It should be 2 for your mic recording.

If this is the case, you can load just one channel of your mic recording by following this answer:
[Read the data of a single channel from a stereo wave file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154400/read-the-data-of-a-single-channel-from-a-stereo-wave-file-in-python)