# Python - Filter local extrema based on relative height

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Using [fuglede's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024165/13490000), it's easy to find the local extrema of a DataFrame column :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Generate a noisy AR(1) sample
np.random.seed(0)
rs = np.random.randn(200)
xs = [0]
for r in rs:
    xs.append(xs[-1]*0.9 + r)
df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns=['data'])

# Find local peaks
df['min'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) > df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) > df.data)]
df['max'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) < df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) < df.data)]

# Plot results
plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')
df.data.plot()
```

Which gives the following graph :

[image]

I now would like to group those extrema in pairs (minimum & extremum that are neighbors, in this order) and remove the pairs where `extremum < minimum + threshold`. By removing I mean replacing the corresponding values in `df['min']` and `df['max']` by `nan`s.
This basically filters the irrelevant small extrema.
I've tried `find_peaks` with various options but none gave the intended results.

Is there an elegant and fast way to do this ?

Comment: What about smoothing the curve and find local min and max on that? Would that be an option? Or Foad's answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023982/pandas-finding-local-max-and-min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the previous, but I think this might be more what you are asking for.

```
threshold = 0.8
points = df.dropna(subset=['min', 'max'], how='all').copy()
ddf = pd.merge(points['min'].dropna().reset_index(),
               points['max'].dropna().reset_index(),
               left_index=True,
               right_index=True)
ddf = ddf[ddf['max'] < (ddf['min'] + threshold)]

# Plot results
plt.scatter(ddf['index_x'], ddf['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(ddf['index_y'], ddf['max'], c='g')
df.data.plot()
```

[image: Graph with relative local extrema]

Although I suspect what you want is actually this:

```
threshold = 3
points = df.dropna(subset=['min', 'max'], how='all').copy()
ddf = pd.merge(points['min'].dropna().reset_index(),
               points['max'].dropna().reset_index(),
               left_index=True,
               right_index=True)
ddf = ddf[ddf['max'] > (ddf['min'] + threshold)]

# Plot results
plt.scatter(ddf['index_x'], ddf['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(ddf['index_y'], ddf['max'], c='g')
df.data.plot()
```

[image: Extremum graph]

To merge this back onto the original dataframe:

```
df['min'] = df.index.map(ddf.set_index('index_x')['min'])
df['max'] = df.index.map(ddf.set_index('index_y')['max'])
```

Comment: Thanks lot, this really does the trick ! How would you replace the unfilterded values of `df['min']` and `df['max']` in `df` by the filtered values stored in `ddf['max']` and `ddf['min']` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed the excellent answer from Foad reported here [Pandas finding local max and min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023982/pandas-finding-local-max-and-min)

Instead of calculating max and min by a shift of 1, you can set a window (number of neighbors) and find the local min and max of your values. Although there is no single window param that will fit perfectly, it reduces the noise substantially.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

# Find peaks in the window
n = 10 #window size
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]]['data']
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I indeed saw Foad's answer but it's not exactly what I need. Basically, I'd need alternatively one min, one max, one min... while removing the (min, max) pairs that are verticaly too close, not horizontally