# Pandas finding local max and min, not plateau values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to find the local max and minimum in pandas DataFrame, at first it looks like this is the same question as [Pandas finding local max and min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023982/pandas-finding-local-max-and-min) but neither of the suggested solutions seems correct.

```
In[876]: import pandas as pd
    ...: 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, -2, 0]})
    ...: 
    ...: # Test 1, missing max in df.iloc[3], min correct
    ...: df['min'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) > df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) > df.data)]
    ...: df['max'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) < df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) < df.data)]
    ...: 
In[877]: df
Out[877]: 
   data  min  max
0     1  NaN  NaN
1     1  NaN  NaN
2     2  NaN  NaN
3     2  NaN  NaN
4     1  NaN  NaN
5     0  NaN  NaN
6     0  NaN  NaN
7    -2 -2.0  NaN
8     0  NaN  NaN
In[878]: 
In[878]: # Test 2, max incorrect, min incorrect
    ...: # max in iloc = 3, 6
    ...: # min in iloc = 1, 7
    ...: df['min'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) >= df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) > df.data)]
    ...: df['max'] = df.data[(df.data.shift(1) <= df.data) & (df.data.shift(-1) < df.data)]
    ...: 
In[879]: df
Out[879]: 
   data  min  max
0     1  NaN  NaN
1     1  1.0  NaN
2     2  NaN  NaN
3     2  NaN  2.0
4     1  NaN  NaN
5     0  NaN  NaN
6     0  NaN  0.0
7    -2 -2.0  NaN
8     0  NaN  NaN
```

I would like to identify the local minimums and maximums, **not the plateau values**.
The correct identification would be:

- maximum in iloc 2 or 3 (Doesn't matter)
- minimum in iloc 7

One solution would be to start writing loops and ifs/elses but it's getting ugly... My guess is that there might be simpler solutions using pandas with some knowhow that I lack, any help would be deeply appreciated.

I'm new to both Python and Stack Overflow so I hope you will forgive any newbie mistakes, cheers.

Comment: Why is max in position 6 incorrect?

Comment: When you have 12344455332 the only local max is values are 5 and 5?

Comment: @DaniMesejo: Max at iloc=6 is between the value of the previous max and before the minimum value in iloc=7, there must be a local min before a new local max.

Comment: @Tarik: Yes. The problem in my example is that plateaus (between local max and min) are registered. Min and max come in pair or as a single (local) max or min. (In your example there are no locals, just a global max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to apply local max and min over the unique consecutive values, so do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, -2, 0]})

# remove consecutive duplicates
res = df[df['data'] != df['data'].shift()]

# find min and max
res['min'] = res.data[(res.data.shift(1) > res.data) & (res.data.shift(-1) > res.data)]
res['max'] = res.data[(res.data.shift(1) < res.data) & (res.data.shift(-1) < res.data)]

# put back in original df
output = pd.concat((df, res[['min', 'max']]), axis=1)
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
   data  min  max
0     1  NaN  NaN
1     1  NaN  NaN
2     2  NaN  2.0
3     2  NaN  NaN
4     1  NaN  NaN
5     0  NaN  NaN
6     0  NaN  NaN
7    -2 -2.0  NaN
8     0  NaN  NaN
```