# How to track consecutive highs in a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to track consecutive highs as shown in this picture in a timeseries with pandas.  See the image below:

[image]

How can this be done with Pandas?

In case you would like to play with a real life example you can download the prices of a stock, say 'MSFT' and use the "close" for your example . There are multiple ways to download the stock price but here is one:

```
import yahooquery

ticker = Ticker('MSFT', asynchronous=True)

df = ticker.history()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough data is returned to perform what you want.  Using [SO find min/max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023982/pandas-finding-local-max-and-min) technique would work by analysing `max` column if data set did have consecutive local maximums.

```
import yahooquery
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

ticker = yahooquery.Ticker('MSFT', asynchronous=True)

df = ticker.history()
df = df.reset_index()

n = 5
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.close.values, np.less_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['close']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.close.values, np.greater_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['close']

plt.scatter(df["date"], df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df["date"], df['max'], c='g')
plt.plot(df["date"], df["close"])
plt.show()
```

[image]