# Find indexes of local maxima/minima in pandas and scipy.signal

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

My goal is to find the indexes of the local maxima and minima of the function in pandas or matplotlib.

Let us say we have a noisy signal with its local maxima and minima already plotted like in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836425/15934571

Here is the code (I just copy and paste it from the link above):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

# Generate a noisy AR(1) sample

np.random.seed(0)
rs = np.random.randn(200)
xs = [0]
for r in rs:
    xs.append(xs[-1] * 0.9 + r)
df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns=['data'])

n = 5  # number of points to be checked before and after

# Find local peaks

df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal,
                    order=n)[0]]['data']

# Plot results

plt.scatter(df.index, df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(df.index, df['max'], c='g')
plt.plot(df.index, df['data'])
plt.show()
```

So, I do not have any idea how to continue from this point and find indexes corresponding to the obtained local maxima and minima on the plot. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You use `df['min'].notna()`, it returns a dataframe in which the row of `min` is not `nan`. To find the index of local minima you can use the `.loc` method.

```
df.loc[df['min'].notna()].index
```

The output result for your example is:

```
Int64Index([0, 11, 21, 35, 43, 54, 67, 81, 105, 127, 141, 161, 168, 187], dtype='int64')
```

You can use the similar procedure to find local maximan.