# Plotting numpy rfft

Tags: python, numpy, plot, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to plot the fft of a wav file, I have successfully completed it using the regular fft but I wanted to experiment with `rfft` as my application was to perform this in music.  When I try to plot `xf` and `yf` (figure 2) I run into an issue where `xf` is half the length of `yf` and I can't figure out why, I assume its due to the negative frequencies missing but I thought changing both function calls to `rfft` and `rfftfreq` would handle it.

```
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

square = 'square.wav'
sine = 'sine.wav'
k = '1Khz.wav'
cello = 'cello.wav'
data, fs = sf.read(k)

#Plot the Signal
N = len(data)
T = 1.0/fs
x = np.linspace(0, (N*T), N)
plt.plot(x, data)
plt.grid()
count = 0

yf = np.fft.rfft(data)
xf = np.fft.rfftfreq(yf.size, d=T)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(xf, yf)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The sizes used for [`numpy.fft.rfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) and [`numpy.fft.rfftfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html) need to match. As such you should use your `data.size` rather `yf.size` (since the size of `yf` is already reduced by not including the negative frequencies) as argument to `rfftfreq`:

```
yf = np.fft.rfft(data)
xf = np.fft.rfftfreq(data.size, d=T)
```

Finally note that as you plot `yf` with `plt.plot(xf, yf)` you would get a warning about the imaginary part being lost. If you are interested in plotting the magnitude of the frequency spectrum, you should rather use `plt.plot(xf, abs(yf))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the frequencies to the sample rate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191172/7919597  or the doc of rfftfreq:

```
signal = np.array([-2, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 3, 5, -3, 4], dtype=float)
fourier = np.fft.rfft(signal)
n = signal.size
sample_rate = 100
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=1./sample_rate)
print(freq)
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d=1./sample_rate)
print(freq)
```