# timestamp of peak frequency python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I have used this code [how to extract frequency associated with fft values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694918/how-to-extract-frequency-associated-with-fft-values-in-python) and added a firwin filter to detect a short high frequency signal. The signal is 1 second long and occurs at random in a wav audio file of x-seconds. My code looks as follows:

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft,fftfreq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wave 
import numpy as np
import sys
import struct

frate,data = wavfile.read('SoundPeep.wav')
#print(frate)
b = signal.firwin(101, cutoff=900, fs= frate, pass_zero=False)
data = signal.lfilter(b, [1.0], data)

w = np.fft.fft(data)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(w))
#print(len(w)/frate)
#print(w.min(), w.max())
# (-0.5, 0.499975)

# Find the peak in the coefficients
idx = np.argmax(np.abs(w))
winner = np.argwhere(np.abs(w) == np.amax(np.abs(w)))

freq = freqs[idx]
freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * frate)
print("HZ")
print(freq_in_hertz)
occurence = idx/frate
print(occurence)
```

The code works well at detecting the peak HZ frequency. My problem is that I want to calculate where the high frequency signal begins in the audio-file. I thought it could be done simply by dividing the index(idx) by the framerate of the recording but this does not seem to work.

Comment: As you have it, `idx` corresponds to the **frequency** of the chirp, and has nothing to do with the **time** that it occurs (ie, where in the audio file).  One possible way to find the time is to do an auto-correlation with a chirp of the same frequency, or there are fancier mathematical approaches using the FFT.

Comment: But the idx is the index of the maximum value of the FFT but this has no correlation with the original data or? The len(w) is equal to len(data)

Answer (score 0):

you could make a sonogram by using a short time fourier transform to see how frequency changes over time. the stft returns 3 values: timestamp, amplitude, and frequency. If the amplitude isnt relevant, you can just use peak detection from there.

Comment: I tried that but the frequency array and the time array are not equal sized and the frequency array contains the same values regardless of the sound file input

Comment: I found another way around but thank you for the answer :)