# Create a wav file from blob audio django

Tags: python, django, audio, blob, wav

On the client side, I am sending a blob audio (wav) file. On the server side, I am trying to convert the blob file to an audio wav file. I did the following:

```
blob = request.FILES['file']
name = "TEST.wav"
audio = wave.open(name, 'wb')
audio.setnchannels(1)
audio.writeframes(blob.read())
```

I thought that converting the blob would be similar to converting a blob image to a jpeg file, but was very incorrect in that assumption. That didn't work; I get an error - "Error: sample width not specified." I then used setsampwidth() and tossed in an arbitrary number between 1 and 4 (after looking at the wave.py source file...I don't know why the bytes have to be between 1 and 4). After that another error is thrown - "Error: sampling rate not specified." How do I specify the sampling rate?

What does the setnchannels(), setsampwidth() methods do? Is there an "easy" way I generate the wav file from the blob?

Comment: is it related to django?

Comment: Yes. I'm using django 1.9 to convert the audio blob to wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, I never do it before.. but, in my test this script below is worked well for me.. ***(But the audio output isn't same like original file)***.

```
>>> nchannels = 2
>>> sampwidth = 2
>>> framerate = 8000
>>> nframes = 100
>>> 
>>> import wave
>>> 
>>> name = 'output.wav'
>>> audio = wave.open(name, 'wb')
>>> audio.setnchannels(nchannels)
>>> audio.setsampwidth(sampwidth)
>>> audio.setframerate(framerate)
>>> audio.setnframes(nframes)
>>> 
>>> blob = open("original.wav").read() # such as `blob.read()`
>>> audio.writeframes(blob)
>>>
```

I found this method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637480/6396981

Finally, by changing the value of `nchannels` and `sampwidth` with `1`. and I got an audio that same with original file.

```
nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 1
framerate = 8000
nframes = 1
```

> Tested under ***Python2***, and got an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 4: invalid start byte` on ***Python3***.

Comment: I've tried it but can't get the same original audio :/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as well. My problem was having a low pitched output compared to the original. I manage to reverse engineer the original audio to get the **nframes**, **samplerate**, and **sampwidth** using **getnframes()**,**getframerate()**, and **getsampwidth()** respectively. At last, I managed to tweak the sample frequency/ frame rate to somehow bring the perfect tone.

The tweaking became perfect at a certain **offset frequency** than the original. Mine worked fine at an offset sum of the sixteenth of the original samplerate.

i.e.

`OffsetFrequency = OriginalFrequency/16`

`Frequency = OriginalFrequency + OffsetFrequency`