# Converting recorded file in JS to WAV to pass as parameter to python file in PHP

Tags: javascript, python, php

I have a voice recorder in Javascript, and the recorded output is accessed through its url in php and passed into a python file to be used by the speech_recognition library for a text conversion like so:

```
$aud = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name'];
$output = shell_exec('python ImageToText.py '. $aud.' 2>&1');
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

Some research revealed that it's because the recording is in webm format, and further research revealed that I can use sox to convert audio from one form to another. I wanted to know if there was a way to do this in php to pass a WAV file to the python file or if there was any other way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: The error message clearly states that `Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV`.

Comment: yeah, don't know  how to resolve it.

Comment: You can't WAV is not supported by the developers.

Comment: oh okay, and can you help in converting to a format that is ?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: speech_recognition in python to convert the audio to text

Comment: I just now read the doc for that library, WAV is supported but it must be in PCM/LPCM format. How are you acquiring the recording? WebM is clearly not supported. Hence that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: the audio is acquired as a blob of type audio/mp3 in my javascript file

Comment: You can pass blob to your python code then use this answer to convert it to WAV. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42288607/7637448

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it out and see.

Comment: If you want I can write a full answer to this question using the advice given in the link.

Comment: That would be appreciated.