# How can I write a wav file using Python?

Tags: python, binary, wav

I want to be able to generate an algorithm to write each frame. I know how to read a `wav` file using the wave module and it generates `\x19\r0\r\`. 
I wanted to be able to in a sense write that and create a `wav` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637350/how-to-write-stereo-wav-files-in-python